# Image upload cakephp cms - croogo

Tags: cakephp, croogo

I need to upload an image in croogo custom form. The form is created using default html tags. I mean not using form helper functions.

Then i use `$_FILES` in my controller function. But no result!

I think `$_FILES` is cleared or something. Can anyone having a solution for this. I need to restrict to clear `$_FILES`. That's my goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can access  that from $this->request->data . All your form data should be there.